# Minimise a CommandBar in UWP with on click event

Tags: uwp, commandbar

I have a commandbar in my UWP application, and I want to hide the bar and only display a ellipsis button when a user click on the hide button. In additional, I would like the commandbar to be opened/shown when the application is being launched.

This is what my command bar looks like,

[image: CommandBar]

And I am trying to get something like this, when I click on the last button:

[image: CommandBar hidden]

**Here is my code for the designer:**

```
<CommandBar IsSticky="True"
                Name="WebViewCommandBar"
                Height="52"
                Background="{StaticResource CitiKioskBackgroundBrush}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed">

        <CommandBar.Transitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </CommandBar.Transitions>

        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>

            <AppBarButton Icon="Back"

                          IsCompact="True"
                          IsEnabled="{Binding CanGoBack,ElementName=webView}"
                          Name="WebViewBackButton"
                          Click="WebViewBackButton_Click" />
            <AppBarButton Icon="Forward"

                          IsCompact="True"
                          IsEnabled="{Binding CanGoForward,ElementName=webView}"
                          Name="WebViewForwardButton"
                          Click="WebViewForwardButton_Click" 
                          Margin="0 0 1450 0"/>

            <AppBarButton 
                          IsCompact="True"
                          Name="WebViewContactButton"
                          Click="WebViewContactButton_Click" 
                          Foreground="White">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Images/icon_smsLocation.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>

            <AppBarButton Icon="Refresh"

                          IsCompact="True"
                          Name="WebViewRefreshButton"
                          Click="WebViewRefreshButton_Click" 
                          Foreground="White"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="DockBottom"

                          IsCompact="True"
                          Name="WebViewHideNavigationButton"
                          Click="WebViewHideNavigationButton_Click" 
                          Foreground="White"/>


        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>

    </CommandBar>
```

**And for my button click event:**

```
private void WebViewHideNavigationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebViewCommandBar.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `IsOpen = false`, `ClosedDisplayMode = Minimal` and `OverflowButtonVisibility = Visible` in your button `click` event.

```
private void MinimalButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyCommandBar.IsOpen = false;
    MyCommandBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Minimal;
    MyCommandBar.OverflowButtonVisibility = CommandBarOverflowButtonVisibility.Visible;
}
```

Set `OverflowButtonVisibility = Collapsed` in `Opening` event

```
private void MyCommandBar_Opening(object sender, object e)
{
    MyCommandBar.OverflowButtonVisibility = CommandBarOverflowButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Set `ClosedDisplayMode = Compact` in `Opened` event

```
private void MyCommandBar_Opened(object sender, object e)
{
    MyCommandBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Compact;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You Should do this, this way -

First Remove your existing command bar because you are implementing it under the grid or frame you implement in page. so you don't need to align it vertically bottom or horizontally stretch.

**XAML**

Here i set app bar mode to compact so every time your page loads it will in compact mode as you want.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsSticky="True" Name="WebViewCommandBar" ClosedDisplayMode="Compact">
        <AppBarButton Icon="DockBottom"
                      IsCompact="True"
                      Name="WebViewHideNavigationButton"
                      Click="WebViewHideNavigationButton_Click" 
                      Foreground="{StaticResource AppBarButtonForeground}"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Add this line of codes out of grid means bottom of where your xaml references is end

> below tihs- mc:Ignorable="d">

and then on app bar button click event -

**C#**

In addtitionally i put if app bar is in **Compact** Mode the it will **Minimal** it else again **Compact** it again

```
private void WebViewHideNavigationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(WebViewCommandBar.ClosedDisplayMode == AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Compact)
    {
        WebViewCommandBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Minimal;
    }
    else
    {
        WebViewCommandBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Compact;
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: Scrennshot]

Your can customize according to you requirement or you can either use toogle button for this.

**Update**

For your commented question-
First set Default in xaml -

> OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed"

and updated **C#**

```
private void WebViewHideNavigationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(WebViewCommandBar.ClosedDisplayMode == AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Compact)
    {
        WebViewCommandBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Minimal;
        WebViewCommandBar.OverflowButtonVisibility = CommandBarOverflowButtonVisibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        WebViewCommandBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Compact;
        WebViewCommandBar.OverflowButtonVisibility = CommandBarOverflowButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, one quick question... because I dont want the ellipsis button to be shown in the command bar, hence I placed "OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed" in the codes.... but even the when the command bar is in minimal mode... there is no "..." shown in the bar

Comment: are you want to show ellipse only in minimal mode ? very simple just think and code wait i am updating answer for this

Comment: Yup yup, I only want to show the ellipse when in minimal mode...Thank you so much^^