# Hiding the ellipse button in command bar

Tags: uwp, commandbar

I am trying to show the ellipse button in the command bar **only** when it is in a **Minimal mode**.

So far, the command bar isn't showing the ellipse button when **on launched**, this is how it looks like:

[image: When on launched]

So when I clicked on my hide button, which is the last button in the picture above, this is how it looks like (in **Minimal mode**):

*it is quite hard to see, but the ellipse is showing....

[image: in mininal mode]

**So here comes the problem**

When I click on the command bar again when it is in the **mininal mode** (second picture), it looks like this:

[image: clicked when in mininal mode]

With the ellipse button **showing**.... I want the command bar to look like how it looks like when **on launched** (first picture) when I clicked on the command bar **again**...

Comment: it is still in minimal mode when you click on hide button it will hide again watch this https://1drv.ms/v/s!AlsWJhYaBXFrc_gkX5ea8AEtqCY

Comment: hmmmm.... I would say that... it is kind of troublesome to have to click like twice to hide the ellipse...

Comment: when you click on ellipsis it is just expanding not go in compact mode it will hide when you click on hide button

Comment: but now... I am trying to not show the ellipse when the command bar is being expand again...

Comment: In other word... I dont want the ellipse to appear at all when it is like "expanded"

Comment: Okay now you already get an answer. You can combine this with previous solution to get you job done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OverflowButtonVisibility = Collapsed` in `Opening` event and `OverflowButtonVisibility = Visible` in `Closing` event

```
private void MyCommandBar_Opening(object sender, object e)
{
    MyCommandBar.OverflowButtonVisibility = CommandBarOverflowButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
}

private void MyCommandBar_Closing(object sender, object e)
{
    MyCommandBar.OverflowButtonVisibility = CommandBarOverflowButtonVisibility.Visible;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to set my command bar open always when launched... this is actually a continue question from this, as the person who asked the previous question did not really understand what I am looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007282/minimise-a-commandbar-in-uwp-with-on-click-event
Please take a look at it, if you are free...

Comment: @thalassophile I will post the answer for that question in that post. I can't answer here because this question is not related to that answer.